# Tengo duads sobre el método main

Tags: java, c#, c++

1. ¿El método `main` puede estar en más de una clase?
2. ¿Sólo se utiliza el de la clase principal para ejecutar todo el programa?
3. Las dos opciones son válidas.

Comment: y esas dudas en que lenguaje? debes usar solo la tag que indique el lenguaje que usas, los otros estan de mas y causan confusión

Comment: en lenguaje java mas que todo

Comment: Por favor mira [ask].. Y lo probaste? o que investigaste al respecto?

Comment: La respuesta correcta es la 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [java](/questions/tagged/java)

> ¿El método `main` puede estar en más de una clase?

Si. En Java debes tener un método llamado `main` en al menos una clase. Debe ser un método estático (esto significa que el método es parte de la clase pero no parte del objeto).

> ¿Sólo se utiliza el de la clase principal para ejecutar todo el programa?

No hay una clase principal. Para ejecutar un programa de Java, hay que decirle a la máquina virtual el nombre de la clase que debe ejecutarse y buscará en ella un método `main`.

#### [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

> ¿El método `main` puede estar en más de una clase?

En C# no existe el método `main`, en su lugar existe el método `Main`. Según [la documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) (traducción mía):

> El método `Main` es el punto de entrada de una aplicación C# [...] Cuando se inicia la aplicación el método `Main` es el primero en ser llamado.

La documentación también establece que el método `Main` puede estar en más de una clase, pero fallará la compilación a no ser que se le diga al compilador qué método `Main` debe usarse como punto de entrada:

> Sólo puede haber un punto de entrada en un programa C#. Si tienes más de una clase con un método `Main`, deberás compilar el programa con la opción `/main` para especificar cuál es el método `Main` que debe usarse como punto de entrada.

> ¿Sólo se utiliza el de la clase principal para ejecutar todo el programa?

De nuevo, no existe ningún concepto parecido a "*clase principal*", la documentación explicita que se usará el método `Main` que se compile como punto de entrada.

#### [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

> ¿El método `main` puede estar en más de una clase? ¿Sólo se utiliza el de la clase principal para ejecutar todo el programa?

El método `main` es una función global, así que no pertenece a ninguna clase, por lo tanto ninguna de las preguntas anteriores tiene sentido en este lenguaje. [En el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) se establece (traducción mía):

> #### 3.6.1 Función `main`
>
> 1. Un programa debe contener una función global llamada `main`, que es el punto designado para iniciar el programa. [...]